# PHP – Defaults file permissions to 644

Tags: php, file, permissions

I don't know why, but PHP, when creating files, for example, using their built-in functions like `file_put_contents()`, it defaults file permissions to `644`.

How can I make it default them to `777` instead? I need it to do so for being able to edit or delete them later using my FTP client.

Comment: 777 is a *terrible* idea. If your FTP client needs 777 permissions, use a different one.

Comment: But anyway, how can I get this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chmod(filename, mode) to change file permissions. A small test to see if it works, important to use clearstatcache() to get an updated answer from PHP:

```
$perms=fileperms("dummy.txt");
echo 'start : ' . substr(sprintf('%o', $perms), -4);
echo '<br />';

$success=chmod("dummy.txt", 0777);
var_dump($success);
echo '<br />';

clearstatcache(); // to make sure we get an updated answer

$perms_chg=fileperms("dummy.txt");
echo 'file permissions are changed to : ' . substr(sprintf('%o', $perms_chg), -4) . ' from : ' . substr(sprintf('%o', $perms), -4);
echo '<br />';

$time=time();
file_put_contents("dummy.txt", $time);

$perms=fileperms("dummy.txt");
echo 'file permissions after writing data to file : ' . substr(sprintf('%o', $perms), -4);

if($perms === $perms_chg)
{
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'file_put_contents has NOT changed file permissions';
}
else
{
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'file_put_contents HAS changed permissions to some default setting'; 
}
```